# Sql remove milliseconds and Date Conversion

Tags: sql

Please could any one suggest me getting the right results?

I have a Date field which results in "2016-07-08 10:09:22.910" format and wish to remove milliseconds and same time wish to convert this field in to "08/07/2016 10:09:22"

I managed to remove the milliseconds by using `CONVERT(VARCHAR, [DateFileCreated], 20)` but unable to convert this in to the desired format.

Please suggest

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: Must not use convert, you need a different format of date. You don't need to convert in String rep.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In SQL Server ,you can use <kbd>[FORMAT available from SQL Server 2012](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/hh213505.aspx)</kbd>

```
SELECT FORMAT ( getdate(), 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss' )
```

**Output:**

```
2016-07-11 07:13:33
```

Comment: yes it worked with bit of a tweaking.. used this one now and it worked FORMAT([DateFileCreated],'dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss')

Answer (score 1):

The reference to `convert()` suggests that you are using SQL Server.  You can see the list of formats supported by `convert()` in the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx).

Format 131 is very close to what you want:

```
select convert(varchar(255), DateFileCreated, 131)
```

In SQL Server 2012+, you can use `format()` to get exactly what you want.  The documentation for this function is [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213505.aspx).

Comment: Sorry Gordon, when tried the above its giving me funny results e.g.  3/10/1437 10:13:05:360AM